# Get value of <select> in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have:

```
<select id="isTitles">
    <option value="true">enable</option>
    <option value="false">disable</option>
</select>
```

on my index.jsp. And I would like to know what had been chosen:

```
response.getWriter().write( "User chose: " + request.getAttribute( "isTitles" ) );
```

But I've got "User chose: null"... = (

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Change your HTML code to:

```
<select id="isTitles" name="isTitles" >
```

The `id` attribute of select tag is mainly for DOM usages, and `name` attribute is to specify the key of a form data.

And then use `request.getParameter("isTitles")`, your will get the right value. `getParameter` is for retrieving parameters from form data and URL query string.  While `getAttribute` is for transfer data through the process chain during the request life cycle.

Comment: @Weibo Li, let me know the difference between **id** and **name** inside html-tag?

Answer (score 6):

You need to pass the name of your  attribute as `name="isTitles"`

```
<select name="isTitles">
</select>
```

`request.getParameter()` understands the name of the parameter

Answer (score 4):

change this `request.getAttribute( "isTitles" )` to `request.getParameter("isTitles" )`

Also there is no name for the select field so you should also give a name to it

```
<select id="isTitles" name="isTitles">
    <option value="true">enable</option>
    <option value="false">disable</option>
</select>


response.getWriter().write( "User chose: " + request.getParameter("isTitles" ) );
```

Comment: @nightin_gale: you should also ensure that your parameter gets to the server eg. by submitting the form. You can debug very easily by watching request.getParameterMap() or printing out all keys in a loop.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
request.getParameter("isTitles")
```

and give name attribute for your select box

```
<select id="isTitles" name="isTitles" >
```